Missing CV libraries in Python in HandTrackingModule
When I try to run the Python code, it works perfectly, but when I use autopyexe to transform it into an executable, it gives me this error, even if the library is apparently installed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cvzone'

I installed the libraries various times but it didn't help at all with the result, I also disabled the antivirus if that was a problem.

Try explicitly including cvzone when using autopyexe. Use the --add-data flag to specify its path during the packaging process. For example:
autopyexe --add-data="<path_to_cvzone_folder>;cvzone" main.py

Replace <path_to_cvzone_folder> with the actual path to the cvzone library folder.
This should ensure that cvzone is bundled correctly with your executable.
